# Why do we have $Q(\alpha, z) = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha, z, \overline{z})$ where $\alpha, z, \overline{z}$ are the roots of $X^3+X+1 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

We are given the polynomial $f = X^3+X+1 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. It is easy to show that $f$ has only one real root, call it $\alpha$, and the other two roots are complex conjucates: $z, \overline{z}$. Let $L=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, z, \overline{z})$ be the splitting field. I want to prove that $L = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha, z)$. 
Is there a straightforward way to show this? I have a proof for this fact, it is not long, but I feel like there should be a simpler explanation, and maybe a more general one. How would you prove this fact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(X-\alpha)(X-z)(X-\overline{z})=X^3+X+1$ so $\alpha+z+\overline{z}=0$, so that $\overline{z}=-z-\alpha$.

Comment: Any polynomial with real coefficients has either real roots or roots in complex conjugate pairs.

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you, I was looking for such explanation. I think your proof shows that given a polynomial over any field $K$, say $f = (x-a_1)...(x-a_n)$ then we can always discard one of the roots when taking the splitting field, i.e $K(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n) = K(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{i-1}, \alpha_{i+1},...,\alpha_n)$. Am I right?

Comment: @Omer: that’s it. It is a particular case of the Vieta‘s formulas between coefficients of a polynomial and its roots. If you didn’t know them, you probably should take a look. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas

Comment: I don’t think you need anybody’s formulas for this: it should be immediate (“obvious”) that the sum of the roots is the negative of the next-highest coefficient.